# updating view table gives an error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a view table `webform_views_welcome_message_2` with column 'moderation','sid'. I want to update the view table.now I caught error as **

> **The target table webform_views_welcome_message_2 of the UPDATE is not updatable**

```
update `webform_views_welcome_message_2`set moderation='1' where sid='1'
```

why I'm getting this error while updating

Answer (score 2):

Update the original table, the view table will be updated automatically as the view table is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

The view tables are virtual tables based on the result-set of an SQL statement, so you cannot update all the view, your view table has to respect some conditions.

have a look to this article hope will be helpful:
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/update-views/sql-update-views.php

or edit the original tables to update datas